# Необходимо найти ошибку в коде

Tags: java

```
class Box {
  double width;
  double height;
  double depth;

  // display volume of a box
  void volume() {
    System.out.print("Volume is ");
    System.out.println(width * height * depth);
  }
}

class BoxDemo3 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Box mybox1 = new Box();
    Box mybox2 = new Box();

    // assign values to mybox1's instance variables
    mybox1.width = 10;
    mybox1.height = 20;
    mybox1.depth = 15;

    /* assign different values to mybox2's
       instance variables */
    mybox2.width = 3;
    mybox2.height = 6;
    mybox2.depth = 9;

    // display volume of first box
    mybox1.volume();

    // display volume of second box
    mybox2.volume();
  }
}
```

Эта программа должна выводить Объем равен 3000.0
Объем равен 162.О

Comment: Так как ты новичок, надо подсказать: тебе необходимо добавить сюда абсолютно весь код с классов(ВЕСЬ). Так же необходимо прикрепить log ошибок(errors in console). И только потом люди посмотрят и разберутся.

Comment: Что выводит программа в данном случае?

Comment: должна выводить ... Но не выводит?

Comment: Нет никакой ошибки, все выводит правильно. Если только вы не хотите чтобы в числе 162.0 вместо нуля выводилась буква О )))))))) Или нужно перевести `Volume is ` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class BoxDemo3 {

  static class Box {
    ...
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 static class Box {
    double width;
    double height;
    double depth;

    // display volume of a box
    void volume() {
        System.out.print("Volume is ");
        System.out.println(width * height * depth);
    }
}

static class BoxDemo3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Box mybox1 = new Box();
        Box mybox2 = new Box();

        // assign values to mybox1's instance variables
        mybox1.width = 10;
        mybox1.height = 20;
        mybox1.depth = 15;

/* assign different values to mybox2's
   instance variables */
        mybox2.width = 3;
        mybox2.height = 6;
        mybox2.depth = 9;

        // display volume of first box
        mybox1.volume();

        // display volume of second box
        mybox2.volume();
    }
}
```